# Guaranteeing the two items are saved or that none are -- across servers

Tags: algorithm, distributed-transactions

Let's say that process P running on some machine has some data `X` that must be saved in MySql_X (on a different machine) and some data `Y` that must be saved in Mysql_Y (on yet another machine). How can I guarantee that either both `X` and `Y` are saved or otherwise neither are saved? What's the algorithm?

For instance (in silly pseudo code):

```
X_transaction = MySql_X.startTransaction(save(X)) //returns null if failure to start transaction 
Y_transaction = MySql_Y.startTransaction(save(Y))

if X_transaction && Y_transaction {
  X_transaction.commit()
  // what if failure happened here?
  Y_transaction.commit()
}
```

This obviously wouldn't work. Because failure could happen in P or MySql_Y on the line noted above and then only X would be saved.

Comment: Two-phase commit is how I've heard this described.

Comment: Correct, this concept is called [Two-phase commit protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol).  There's no perfect algorithm resilient to all failures; there are various algorithms which have advantages and disadvantages.